# Center Align Column when exporting from Access to Excell

Tags: vba

I have a query in Access that I export to Excel.  Everything works fine, but I want to add one bit of formatting.  I would like to select column C in the excel spreadsheet and have it centered. Seems simple enough, but I can find nothing that works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried to use [macro recorder in Excel](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html)?

Answer (score 0):

How about this line?

```
Columns("C").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

More information can be found in this url.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822120(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822120%28v=office.15%29.aspx)